# How to add cancel button in PopupPanel in Gwt

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gwt2

I am new to programming.

I have vertical panel.A button(lblAddFolderIcon) is added on the verticalPanel and also some widgets.

on click of b1 there should be a popup panel with some more widgets and two button with add and cancel.

My Code:

```
   lblAddFolderIcon.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            String childFolder = item.getText();
            String[] mainRepository=getPath(item);
            String objectId=item.getTitle();

            final AddFolderPopup addFolderPopup = new AddFolderPopup(childFolder,mainRepository[0],objectId);
            addFolderPopup.setHeight("300px");
            addFolderPopup.setWidth("502px");
            addFolderPopup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {

                public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int left = (Window.getClientWidth() - offsetWidth) / 3;
                    int top = (Window.getClientHeight() - offsetHeight) / 3;
                    addFolderPopup.setPopupPosition(left, top);
                }
            });
            //addFolderPopup.show();
            addFolderPopup.addFolderGui();
        }
    });
```

---

```
    public class AddFolderPopup extends PopupPanel {
VerticalPanel vpPopupl = new VerticalPanel();
private String childFolder;
private String mainRepository;
private String objectId;

public AddFolderPopup(){
    super(true);
}
public AddFolderPopup(String childFolder, String mainRepository, String objectId) {
    this.childFolder = childFolder;
    this.mainRepository = mainRepository;
    this.objectId = objectId;   

}
public void addFolderGui() {
         // some widget to design Gui and
      Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                               /* i Dont Know what should i write here 
                                  so that this popupwindow is closed
                                */
                }
    });
      }
    }
```

Plz suggest some code to close this popup window and 
also whether my approach is correct.

Comment: a cancel button on a popup panel? you sure you don't want a dialog box?

Comment: it should be window which comes upon the back screen..
if Dialog box satisfies the need , it will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your click handler's anonymous class: 
AddFolderPopup.this.hide();

Answer (score 3):

try call the 
 `hide()` 
in your cancel's onclick